# global yocto AM_CFLAGS to pass to the gcc compiler

Tags: gcc, yocto, automake, address-sanitizer

I am trying to enable GCC ASAN globally in my automake based project.

I am trying to enable GCC ASAN in my automake based project.
GCC docs says we can enable ASAN by setting -fsanitize=address CFLAG.
I can enable ASAN for a perticular recipe by adding AM_CFLAGS = "-fsanitize=address" in its makefile.am file and its working fine. but don't know how to set it globally. Is there any way we can set it globally ??

1. Tries to set TARGET_CFLAGS = "-fsanitize=address" in poky/meta/conf/bitbake.conf but that didn't help.
2. Tried setting TARGET_CFLAGS_append = "-fsanitize=address" in machine/.conf but this also didn't help.

Comment: Not sure, but in [security-flags.inc](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/conf/distro/include/security_flags.inc), Yocto adds default cflags with `TARGET_CC_ARCH_append_class-target = " ${SECURITY_CFLAGS}"` so maybe you can try to append your flag too?

Comment: Note you have to add a space when you use _append `TARGET_CFLAGS_append = " -fsanitize=address"`